# WhichBrowser Javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, browser

Im am trying to use Whichbrowser from http://whichbrowser.net/ in one of my projects. Im running it on WAMP and have followed the instructions on the site.

the code on the webpage is  :

```
<HTML>

<head>
<script>
(function(){var p=[],w=window,d=document,e=f=0;p.push('ua='+encodeURIComponent(navigator.userAgent));e|=w.ActiveXObject?1:0;e|=w.opera?2:0;e|=w.chrome?4:0;
e|='getBoxObjectFor' in d || 'mozInnerScreenX' in w?8:0;e|=('WebKitCSSMatrix' in w||'WebKitPoint' in w||'webkitStorageInfo' in w||'webkitURL' in w)?16:0;
e|=(e&16&&({}.toString).toString().indexOf("\n")===-1)?32:0;p.push('e='+e);f|='sandbox' in d.createElement('iframe')?1:0;f|='WebSocket' in w?2:0;
f|=w.Worker?4:0;f|=w.applicationCache?8:0;f|=w.history && history.pushState?16:0;f|=d.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen?32:0;f|='FileReader' in w?64:0;
  p.push('f='+f);p.push('r='+Math.random().toString(36).substring(7));p.push('w='+screen.width);p.push('h='+screen.height);var s=d.createElement('script');
s.src='detect.php?' + p.join('&');d.getElementsByTagName('head')      [0].appendChild(s);})();
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
Browsers = new WhichBrowser();
alert("You are using " + Browsers);
});
</script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

its probably a simple JavaScript error in my code as JavaScript isn't my 1st language so to speak but my page is just loading blank and doing nothing.
 Is anyone having the same problem or could help me with an answer.
Thanks

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the console. Read the error messages. *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*

Answer (score 0):

First problem: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

If you change your onload to this, the first error will be resolved, but a new one will be revealed:

```
window.onload = function(){
    Browsers = new WhichBrowser();
    alert("You are using " + Browsers);
};
```

You now have the next problem: `WhichBrowser is not defined`

So now you have to properly create a new WhichBrowser object.
This will guide you through the process: https://github.com/WhichBrowser/WhichBrowser/blob/master/README.md